# How do i return two alerts in JS?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I wrote this code for validate password and i need to show user two different alerts.

1. (pw.length < 8) when this condition executed "Password need minimum 8 characters"
2. (pw != cpw) "Passwords does not match"

I already tried all if statements but it not gonna help.

```
<script>
    function validatePassword(){
        
        var pw= document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
        var cpw= document.getElementById("txtCPassword").value;

        if((pw.length < 8)||(pw != cpw))
            {
                alert("please enter the correct password")
                return false;
                Event.preventDefault();
            }
        return true;
    }
    
</script>
```

Does anyone know if something...

Comment: Do you need to show 2 alerts? Because if txtPassword is invalid, txtCPassword could be ignored.

Comment: `Event.preventDefault();` is an error since you do not declare Event anywhere, but the return keeps it from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean and two if statements. Return the boolean at the end for true or false.

```
function validatePassword() {
  const pw = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
  const cpw = document.getElementById("txtCPassword").value;
  let isValid = true;

  if (pw.length < 8) {
    alert('Password is not long enough. Minimum length is 8 characters.');
    isValid = false;
  }

  if(pw !== cpw)) {
    alert('Passwords do not match'.);
    isValid = false;
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

Or have both messages in one alert using an array

```js
function validatePassword() {
  const pw = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
  const cpw = document.getElementById("txtCPassword").value;
  const errors = [];

  if (pw.length < 8) {
    errors.push('Password is not long enough. Minimum length is 8 characters.');
  }

  if(pw !== cpw)) {
     errors.push('Passwords do not match.');
  }

  if (errors.length) {
    alert(errors.join('\n'));
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is most basic version you can use this type of code.

```js
function validatePassword(){
        var pw= document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
        var cpw= document.getElementById("txtCPassword").value;

        if((pw.length < 8))
            {
                alert("please enter the correct password")
                return false;
            } else if((cpw != pw)) {
                alert("Passwords does not match")
            } else {
            alert("Password is correct!")
        return true;
        }
    }
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="txtPassword">
  <input type="text" id="txtCPassword">
  <input onclick="event.preventDefault();validatePassword()" type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

This will do.

Comment: The question doesn't use the same ID for both inputs. This also doesn't address the question of showing two alerts.

Comment: @MatSchaffer I guess it'll do

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
        var pw= document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
        var cpw= document.getElementById("txtCPassword").value;
    function validatePassword(){
        


        if(pw.length < 8)
            {
                alert("Password need minimum 8 characters")
            }
        if(pw != cpw){
                alert("Passwords does not match")
            }

    }
```

Comment: i already tried that

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to show 2 alerts. When txtPassword is invalid, users have to retype both passwords whether passwords match or not. There is no point in showing `"Passwords does not match"` message in that case.

To know how to show 2 alerts, see my second code.

**First, here is another solution:**

```js
const FORM = document.querySelector('#form');
const PSW = document.querySelector('#txtPassword');
const C_PSW = document.querySelector('#txtCPassword');

FORM.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!validatePassword()) return;
    console.log('Submitted');
})

function validatePassword() {
    let pw = PSW.value;
  let cpw = C_PSW.value;
  
  if (pw.length < 8) {
    alert('please enter the correct password');
    return;
  } else if (pw !== cpw) {
    alert('Passwords does not match');
    return;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="password" id="txtPassword">
  <input type="password" id="txtCPassword">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

**To show 2 alerts:**

```js
function validatePassword() {
  let pw = PSW.value;
  let cpw = C_PSW.value;

  if (pw.length < 8) {
    alert('please enter the correct password');
    if (pw !== cpw) {
      alert('Passwords does not match');
    }
    return;
  } else if (pw !== cpw) {
    alert('Passwords does not match');
    return;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: the show two alerts example at the end is pretty bad. You should not copy the same code twice.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like that part either.